# Some doubts regarding determinants

Tags: matrices, determinant

When can $\det(AB)$ be written as $\det(A) \det(B)$ and when not ?

Is it possible that while we multiply two matrices $AB = C$ that determinant of $A$ and $B$ is not 0 but determinant of $C$ is $0$?

I'm a beginner in this topic. So please don't mind if my question seems trivial.

Comment: It is *always* true that if $\;A,B\;$ are square matrices of the same order then $\;\det(AB)=\det A\cdot\det B\;$

Comment: What if A and B are rectangular matrices ? And can you provide a proof for your statement ?@Joanpemo

Comment: @SanchayanDutta Determinants are only defined for square matrices.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ had non zero determinant, they can be decomposed into the product of elementary matrices. It is clear that $C$ is also a product of elementary matrices and invertible.

Comment: Determinant is a number so it cant be just multiplication is 0 as one of them has to be $0$ for it to happen and theres a difference between $\text{O}$ of matrix and $0$ of a determinant

Comment: @SanchayanDutta I probably could, yet (1) Echan already gave you a good hint, (2) it appears in any decent book in Linear Algebra, (3) It appears en many, many sites in the web. Google it. You have two here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product#Proof_1 The second one seems more elementary.